# Exile the teacher also to the city of refuge?

Tags: city-of-refuge, maseches-makos, chinuch-education

In [Makkot 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.10a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we learn that if a man is exiled to a city of refuge, his teacher must be exiled with him to continue to teach him Torah there:

> [The Sages] taught: [If] a student is exiled [to the city of refuge], his teacher is exiled with him, [so that the student can continue studying Torah with him there,] as it is stated: 
>   [And he shall flee to one of these cities] and live, [Deut. 4:42]
>   from which it is derived: Perform some [actions] for [the unintentional murderer so] that [life in the city] will be [conducive to] living for him. [Since Torah study is an integral component of his life, arrangements must be made to ensure its continuity.] 
>   Rabbi Zeira says: From here one learns that a person should not teach a student who is not fit, [as that may result in the teacher following the student into exile].

Sounds like a bad deal for teachers!

I have a couple of questions:

- Why does it have to be HIS teacher, as opposed to "**A**" teacher?
- Why does the teacher have to be exiled, as opposed to visiting his student periodically?
  Perhaps the authorities can appoint a resident teacher at a city of refuge, to teach ALL the refugees there.

Is all this addressed anywhere?

Comment: Wow, I thought this was one of the functions of the Leviim who live there.  Also, what about all that teacher's *other* students?  This sounds highly impractical -- one student transgressing can banish his entire academy??

Answer (score 1):

Ritva (quoted by artscroll) answers that this law applies even if there is an academy in place in the city of refuge, **for not every student merits to study successfully under every teacher**.

In other words the exilee needs his own teacher to make sure he will continue to learn well.